# Proof that a finite union of finite sets is finite

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

The following proof is based on a proof which can be found in the Book "Einführung in die Mengenlehre" (Second Edition) by Oliver Deiser page 99. The reasoning and the set up are a bit different though. I hope that I didn't make a subtle mistake. *It would be great if somebody could verify the proof*.

The proof uses the follwing results:

i) $A$ is an infinite set $\Rightarrow$ $\exists S, S: \mathbb{N}\stackrel{inj}\longrightarrow A$.

ii) $\emptyset \neq N \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ and $N$ is finite $\Rightarrow$ $\max N$ exists

iii) $N \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ and $N$ is unbounded in $\mathbb{N} \Rightarrow N$ is infinite

iv) $|A| \le |B|$ and $A$ is infinite $\Rightarrow B$ is infinite

---

That a finite union of finite sets is finite is equivalent to the following statement:

*Let $P$ be finite and $\bigcup P$ infinite. Then there exists a $B \in P$ such that $B$ is infinite.* (Note that $P$ is not necessarily a partition.)

Proof:

Since $\bigcup P$ is infinite there must exist a function $S: \mathbb{N}\stackrel{inj}\longrightarrow \bigcup P$.

Let $N_B := \{n\in \mathbb{N} : S(n) \in B\}$ for $B \in P$.

Suppose that $N_B$ is bounded in $\mathbb N$ for all $B \in P$. This will lead to a contradiction:

Let $U:=\{\max{N_B} : B \in P, N_B \neq \emptyset\}$.

$U$ can not be empty and is also finite, because $P$ is finite. Therefore $m := \max{U}$ must exist, which holds the inequality $m \ge \max{N_B}$ for all $B \in P$.

$S(m+1) \in \bigcup{P}$ since $S$ is defined on all natural numbers. This leads to $S(m + 1) \in B$ for a $B \in P$ and further to $m + 1 \in N_B$. This contradicts the definition of $m$.

It follows that there must exist at least one $B \in P$ such that $N_B$ is unbounded in $\mathbb{N}$ which means that $N_B$ is infinite.

The restriction of $S$ to $N_B \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ is $S|_{N_B} : N_B \stackrel{inj}\longrightarrow B$ which is equivalent to $|N_B| \le |B|$. The infinity of $N_B$ then is a witness for the infinity of $B$. This concludes the proof.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: I've hoped that somebody could verify the proof.

Comment: In the original proof it is followed through contradiction that $U$ is unbounded. Then after a construction of an injective function from $U$ to $P$ it is concluded that $P$ is infinite which contradicts the premise that $P$ is finite.